# Django: When to put code in serializers.py or views.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, backend

I am kind of confused about when should I put code in serializers.py or views.py.

My understanding is that serializers.py is where data is manipulated + converted between front and backend.

But so far, my understanding is that only the validation function and maybe a Meta class need to be in serializers.py. I feel like I can just manipulate the database directly in views.py. Like, I can just import the model in views.py and then do datModel.objects.create() or datModel.objects.get().someAttribute = somethingNew.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Models and Views, my thinking is that the less logic about manipulating the model in the view the better, leave the view to focus on fetching the data, minimum data manipulation code via encapsulation, then present the data to the view

here is the overly simplified example

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    stock_level = model.Integer(..)

    def reduce_stock_level(number)
        # insert some 100 lines of validation
        self.stock_level -= number
        self.save()
```

In your view:

```py
def checkout(...):
    ...
    product = Product.object.get(...)
    product.reduce_stock_level(1)
```

is cleaner than in the view to do the same thing

```py
def checkout(...):
    product = Product.object.get(...)
    # insert 100 lines of validation
    product.stock_level -= 1
    product.save()
```

Also you can reuse the method in other places and seems more pythonic:

```py
for product in Products.objects.all():
    product.reduce_stock_level(10)
```